# ESP8266 AES encrypt - decrypt

Tags: c, arduino, base64, aes, esp8266

I'm sure I'm doing the decoding and the decryption wrongly, but I don't know what exactly.

```
#include "AES.h"
#include "Base64.h"

AES aes;

// Our AES key. Note that is the same that is used on the Node-Js side but as hex bytes.
byte key[] = {0x7e, 0x4e, 0x42, 0x38, 0x43, 0x63, 0x4f, 0x4c, 0x23, 0x4a, 0x21, 0x48, 0x3f, 0x7c, 0x59, 0x72};

// The unitialized Initialization vector
byte iv[N_BLOCK] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

// Our message to encrypt. Static for this example.
String msg = "{\"data\":{\"value\":300}, \"SEQN\":700 , \"msg\":\"IT WORKS!!\" }";

uint8_t generate_random_unit8()
{
  uint8_t really_random = *(volatile uint8_t *)0x3FF20E44;
  return really_random;
}

// Generate a random initialization vector
void generate_iv(byte *vector)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N_BLOCK; i++)
  {
    vector[i] = (byte)generate_random_unit8();
  }
}

void encrypt()
{
  char b64data[200];
  byte cipher[1000];
  byte iv[N_BLOCK];

  generate_iv(iv);

  base64_encode(b64data, (char *)iv, N_BLOCK);
  String IV_base64 = String(b64data);
  Serial.println(" IV b64: " + IV_base64);

  int b64len = base64_encode(b64data, (char *)msg.c_str(), msg.length());

  Serial.println(" The lenght is:  " + String(b64len));

  // Encrypt! With AES128, our key and IV, CBC and pkcs7 padding
  aes.do_aes_encrypt((byte *)b64data, b64len, cipher, key, 128, iv);

  Serial.println("Cipher size: " + String(aes.get_size()));

  base64_encode(b64data, (char *)cipher, aes.get_size());
  Serial.println("Encrypted data in base64: " + String(b64data));

  decrypt(b64data, IV_base64, aes.get_size());
}

void decrypt(String b64data, String IV_base64, int size)
{
  char data_decoded[200];
  char iv_decoded[200];
  byte out[200];
  char temp[200];
  b64data.toCharArray(temp, 200);
  base64_decode(data_decoded, temp, b64data.length());
  IV_base64.toCharArray(temp, 200);
  base64_decode(iv_decoded, temp, IV_base64.length());
  aes.do_aes_decrypt((byte *)data_decoded, size, out, key, 128, (byte *)iv_decoded);
  char message[msg.length()];
  base64_decode(message, (char *)out, b64data.length());
  printf("Out %s \n", message);
}

void setup_aes()
{
  aes.set_key(key, sizeof(key)); // Get the globally defined key
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  encrypt();
  delay(1000);
}
```

The decoded message should be `{"data":{"value":300}, "SEQN":700 , "msg":"IT WORKS!!"`. However I'm getting `{"data":{"value":300}, "SEQN":700 , "msg":"IT WORKS!!" }�������������������������`. I would assume that the char length is not correct?

Comment: As recycler pointed out, the returned string lacks the terminator. You can, however, add it just to the decoded buffer with char message[msg.length() + 1]; in the decrypt. However I found that your program is very confused. Please avoid unnecessary conversions (why should the message be a string? Why do you have to convert back and forth to strings? And most important: why did you convert the plaintext to base64?)

Comment: how is `generate_random_unit8` random at all?

Comment: @IvayloIvanov, I will works with this in ESP8266, do you can help me? I needs know where are I get the librarys `#include "AES.h"
#include "Base64.h"`.

Comment: @dandavis, that address is reported to return a hardware and unbiased random value on each read.

Comment: Actually those strange characters you see at the end are \0 characters, I guess your AES library doesn't support padding so you need to just trim the response from \0 . it is a bad idea to use constant value to cut your string, depending on string length AES will add \0 to end to make is equal to block size (128 your case)

Answer (score 1):

If you encode, you should finalize the string with \0 so in decoded data, the \0 is also there and the printf can correctly end on \0.

The fix would  be
`int b64len = base64_encode(b64data, (char *)msg.c_str(), msg.length()+1);`
This ensures the implicit \0 byte to be included. The compiler adds this to msg string automatically.

Try it!

Answer (score 1):

I was recently having the same issue myself and I spent several hours trying to figure this out. Ivanov, you have a good point about the length of the encoded data. The main problem is basically when the AES encrypt function creates additional padding and the decrypt function not being able to remove it.

This does not have anything to do with the null termination of the string or the fact that it lacks a terminator. The problem is actually solved by simply omitting the last 5 padding from the decrypted string.

**Edit** This is actually more than just omitting 5 characters from the end. As I found out that the amount of gibberish or padding varies depending on the length of your original JSON, it makes more sense to trim the string by detecting the end of the JSON string.

I am providing my (updated) working code for reference. I hope this helps anyone who also has this issue! Good luck with your project!

```
#include "AES.h"
#include "Base64.h"

AES aes;

// Our AES key. Same in NodeJS but in hex bytes
byte key[] = { 0x2B, 0x7E, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xAE, 0xD2, 0xA6, 0xAB, 0xF7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xCF, 0x4F, 0x3C };
// The unitialized Initialization vector (16-bit)
byte iv[N_BLOCK] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

// NodeMCU side raw message
String msg = "{\"x\":10, \"y\":20, \"z\":30 \"lamp_stat\":\"ON  This is a sentence. Testing testing testing\"}";

uint8_t generate_random_unit8()
{
  uint8_t really_random = *(volatile uint8_t *)0x3FF20E44;
  return really_random;
}

// Generate a random initialization vector
void generate_iv(byte *vector)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N_BLOCK; i++)
  {
    vector[i] = (byte)generate_random_unit8();
  }
}

void encrypt()
{
  char b64data[200];
  byte cipher[1000];
  byte iv[N_BLOCK];

  generate_iv(iv);

  base64_encode(b64data, (char *)iv, N_BLOCK);
  String IV_base64 = String(b64data);
  Serial.println(" IV b64: " + IV_base64);

  int b64len = base64_encode(b64data, (char *)msg.c_str(), msg.length());

  Serial.println(" The lenght is:  " + String(b64len));

  // Encrypt! With AES128, our key and IV, CBC and pkcs7 padding
  aes.do_aes_encrypt((byte *)b64data, b64len, cipher, key, 128, iv);

  Serial.println("Cipher size: " + String(aes.get_size()));

  base64_encode(b64data, (char *)cipher, aes.get_size());
  Serial.println("Encrypted data in base64: " + String(b64data));

  //decrypt(b64data, IV_base64, aes.get_size());
}

void decrypt(String b64data, String IV_base64, int lsize)
{
  char data_decoded[300];
  char iv_decoded[300];
  byte out[300];
  char temp[300];
  b64data.toCharArray(temp, 300);
  base64_decode(data_decoded, temp, b64data.length());
  IV_base64.toCharArray(temp, 300);
  base64_decode(iv_decoded, temp, IV_base64.length());
  aes.do_aes_decrypt((byte *)data_decoded, lsize, out, key, 128, (byte *)iv_decoded);
  char message[msg.length()];
  base64_decode(message, (char *)out, aes.get_size());
  for (int i = 0; i < aes.get_size(); i++)
  {
    char curChar = (char)message[i];
    if (curChar != '}')
      temp[i] = curChar;
    else
    {
      temp[i] = curChar;
      temp[i+1] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
  String result = String((char *)temp);
  Serial.println(result);
}

void setup_aes()
{
  aes.set_key(key, sizeof(key)); // Get the globally defined key
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop()
{
  encrypt();
  decrypt("ipYk12VCYyD+aJ7KL7lO8L5zOq71XvsLzp650gKBFgQor7GHs98QpQSjQOZdhCwggq2Ehf4nVNwTeK3VjtqMVJRGBw9YViARXCTOGqctjFc=", "+eNzSlRRPi0YZhrp5ctpnA==", 83);
  delay(8000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was wrong..

`base64_decode(message, (char *)out, b64data.length());`

should be

`base64_decode(message, (char *)out, 75);` - the length of the encoded data - 1

At least the PoC works.